# Zathura shortcut/feedkeys configuration for recolouring

Tags: pdf, zathura

I used to have the following in my .zathurarc config, which used to allow me to change the colour scheme by pressing Shift-1, Shift-2, Shift-3, Shift-4, to  switch to original colour scheme, amber on dark bluish-grey, green on black, blue on black, respectively:

```
map ! feedkeys  ":set recolor-lightcolor \#ffffff<Return>:set recolor-darkcolor \#000000<Return>" # original (black on white) 
map @ feedkeys  ":set recolor-lightcolor \#0a0a12<Return>:set recolor-darkcolor \#ff9900<Return>" # amber on dark slate
map \# feedkeys ":set recolor-lightcolor \#000000<Return>:set recolor-darkcolor \#00B800<Return>" # green on black
map $ feedkeys  ":set recolor-lightcolor \#002b36<Return>:set recolor-darkcolor \#839496<Return>" # bluish (midnight mode)
```

Recent versions of zathura don't work with this, specifically they don't seem to like the `<Return>` bit, I think. Does anyone know how I might amend these to work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above solution did not work for me (using Zathura 0.4.7), but here's what did work:

(Note: also added "set recolor true" just for testing convenience)

```
set recolor true

# midnight mode    
map <F1> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-lightcolor \#002b36"    
map <F2> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-darkcolor \#839496"    
map ! feedkeys "<F1><Return><F2><Return>"    
# amber on dark slate        
map <F3> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-lightcolor \#0a0a12"    
map <F4> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-darkcolor \#ff9900"    
map @ feedkeys "<F3><Return><F4><Return>"    
# green on black    
map <F6> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-lightcolor #000000"    
map <F7> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-darkcolor \#00B800"    
map \# feedkeys "<F6><Return><F7><Return>"    
# original (black on white)    
map <F8> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-lightcolor \#ffffff"    
map <F9> focus_inputbar ":set recolor-darkcolor \#000000"    
map $ feedkeys "<F8><Return><F9><Return>"
```

Comment: Many thanks! I've been struggling trying to get this to work in recent versions, but the config code here works! (At least, for now....)

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a **workaround** to this problem.

My `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` file:

---

```
# midnight mode
map <F1> feedkeys ":set recolor-lightcolor \#002b36<Return>"
map <F2> feedkeys ":set recolor-darkcolor \#839496<Return>"
map ! feedkeys "<F1><F2>"
# amber on dark slate
map <F3> feedkeys ":set recolor-lightcolor \#0a0a12<Return>"
map <F4> feedkeys ":set recolor-darkcolor \#ff9900<Return>"
map @ feedkeys "<F3><F4>"
# green on black
map <F6> feedkeys ":set recolor-lightcolor #000000<Return>"
map <F7> feedkeys ":set recolor-darkcolor \#00B800<Return>"
map \# feedkeys "<F6><F7>"
# original (black on white)
map <F8> feedkeys ":set recolor-lightcolor \#ffffff<Return>"
map <F9> feedkeys ":set recolor-darkcolor \#000000<Return>"
map $ feedkeys "<F8><F9>"
```

As You can see above, according to `zathurarc` manpage ([`ZATHURARC(5)`](https://www.mankier.com/5/zathurarc)), I'm `mapping` the `set` commands to `Special keys` and then these `maps` to my binds. Note that, I don't have any binds in Zathura to these keys (`<F[1-8]>`).

**Edit:** Since `F5` is assigned to presentation mode I've changed `map <F5>` to `map <F6>` and the other `maps` iteratively up.